# .htaccess help needed rewrite

Tags: php, forms, .htaccess

i have a problem,. i am creating a app in php, with the below code .htacces all links works fine.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /courier/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) /courier/index.php?view=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

now my links are like

```
http://localhost/courier/order-search/
```

But i have a search form with few fields, method is GET, so the link is like this below

```
http://localhost/courier/order-search/?test=a&test1=b
```

So , my question is how can i get the values of test and test1 fields using GET?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your PHP code just do `$_GET['test'] and $_GET['test1']`

Comment: In `index.php` you get `order-search/?test=a&test1=b` as `$_GET['view']`. Did you check it? why not dump `phpinfo(INFO_VARIABLES);`?

Comment: i got $_GET['view'] = order-search/ php variables are out of charactor limit.

Answer (score 1):

Add the QSA flag.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) /courier/index.php?view=$1 [L,QSA]
```